# Trust bluetooth 3.0 USB adapter on Linux

Tags: linux, usb, drivers, bluetooth

I bought [Trust bluetooth 3.0 USB adapter.](http://www.trust.com/en/all-products/17772-bluetooth-30-usb-adapter) It works on my windows PC, but I'm not able to use it on my Ubuntu machine.
`lsusb` shows me this device

```
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0cf3:3002 Atheros Communications, Inc.
```

but seems that it doesn't recognize device as bluetooth adapter.

`hciconfig -a` doesn't print anything as well as `hcitool dev`.

**update**

Ubuntu version: 12.04.4 LTS

Kernel version: 3.5.0-46-generic

**update**

Same thing on kernel version 3.11.0-12-generic, ubuntu 13 (just downloaded from internet)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nice research, and good troubleshooting on the first try! Great question. You didn't include your Ubuntu version and kernel version, though. ;)

It seems this is a [widespread kernel issue](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=42442); a regression from 2.6.36. From the comments in the bugzilla thread (which have very many links to other useful resources; please read them!) you can find a link to this [patch](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.linux.kernel/1262485) which seems to have fixed the issue for at least one person.

Try googling for your PCI ID (0cf3:3002) and looking at some of the other mailing list and bugzilla posts about this if you are unable to get it working by patching your firmware. Great detective work so far!

Comment: You are right, this is kernel regression :( Installed ubuntu 7.1 and it worked.

Comment: I think if you patch the firmware like it was suggested, you can fix the issue yourself. You don't have to recompile the kernel because firmware is installed in the `/lib/firmware` directory.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do now. I tried older kernel version to confirm the kernel issue. Thanks.